# How do you tell if you have a complete ban or if you are being throttled?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am currently unable to ask questions on SO, but I don't know if I am banned from asking or if I am throttled.  Is there any indicator that lets you distinguish between the two?

Comment: The message you get would tell you. What message do you receive

Comment: Do you get an error about not asking more than one question a week? Or about the quality of your question you are trying to post?

Comment: @cluemein maybe it was the old type of ban? I'm still not completely sure how the new system works with pre-existing banned accounts. I'd wait to hear an answer from official staff.

Comment: ...or due to 4 downvoted questions in the last 6 hours

Comment: For the record, you are actually blocked right now, not just rate-limited.

Comment: Is it not incredibly ironic, though, that he asked a question on here about getting too many downvotes, and got 18 downvotes? That's just cruel haha.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Why have I been barred from posting questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234517/why-have-i-been-barred-from-posting-questions), users who are being throttled will see this message (emphasis mine):

> You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, **the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited.** For more information, visit the Help Center.

As for why you don't see this message and are completely banned, I'm not sure of how the new system works with pre-existing banned accounts, so I'll wait for a moderator or staff to respond to that.